# SQL Server replace special characters in tables temporary - using view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, replace, special-characters

I have a sql view created that returns all my necessary data and works great. For example, the view column names are CompanyName, Person, Title.  I'm trying to write a report (pipe delimited) that will strip these special characters: ("" , ; ~, *) and return the data but not permanently update the view or permanently update the tables.

example:

```
Widgets & Widgets Joe President,Pro Tempore
```

Should Become

```
Widgets Widgets | Joe | President Pro Tempore
```

I do a query in the view and my data comes back, but no amount of the replace function will replace the ampersands, commas, tildes etc.  I just need to get this to a point in sql where I can export to a pipe delimited file. I do not want to permanently change the data, I just need a one-off report made.

Can anyone please help here?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql

Comment: That, and show us what you tried that did not work

Comment: What do mean "no amount of replace function .."  of course some amount will work.   One replace per character will work.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (I don't know if this is your database) you can use the REPLACE function to replace any character you want with another one of your choice. Nesting multiple REPLACE calls you can replace all the special characters you want with a single statement.

Example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'"','|'),',','|'),';','|'),'~','|'),'*','|') FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace, replace, replace:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(company + ' | ' + name + ' | ' + title, '~', ''
                                      ), ',', ''
                              ), ';', ''
                       ), '*', ''
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you use Translate function to replace multiple characters at once :

```
select TRANSLATE('Widgets &;, Widgets Joe President,Pro Tempore','";~,*','     ')
```